# SQL:How to include empty or null Year in Group By

Tags: mysql

I want to get the `COUNT` by year and include year with the empty or zero values

heres my current query

```
SELECT YEAR(`date_incident`) as Year
,COUNT(`tblrespond`.`patient_no`) as Total  
FROM  `tblrespond` 
Inner Join `tblincident` 
On `tblincident`.`incident_no` = `tblrespond`.`incident_no` 
Inner Join `tblpatients` 
On `tblpatients`.`patient_no` = `tblrespond`.`patient_no` 
Group By YEAR(`date_incident`)
```

but this query skips the year with empty data

what i want is to generate like this.

```
YEAR       Total
-----     ------
2011        10
2012        7
2013        0
2014        12
2015        0
2016        5
```

in my current query. the year `2013` & `2015` will be skipped.

it has 3 relationship table `tblrespond`,`tblincident`,`tblpatients`
both `tblincident` and `tblpatients` are connected to the `tblrespond`.

Comment: mysql   or sql-server?

Comment: @scaisEdge im sorry. i think its mysql. i just included the suggested tags. ill edit it.

Comment: @Ullas sorry. its mysql coz i use xammp

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code (e.g.the first or second 'p' of 'xampp').

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have all the year in  you columns value you must provide a table for years and left join query

```
  SELECT t.myYear as Year, ifnull(COUNT(`tblrespond`.`patient_no`), 0) as Total 
  from (
  select 2011 as myYear
  union 
  select 2012
  union
  select 2013
  union 
  select 2014
  union 
  select 2015
  union 
  select 2016
  ) t 
  LEFT JOIN  `tblrespond`  on t.myYear = `tblrespond`.YEAR(`date_incident`)
  Inner Join `tblincident` On `tblincident`.`incident_no` = `tblrespond`.`incident_no` 
  Inner Join `tblpatients` On `tblpatients`.`patient_no` = `tblrespond`.`patient_no`
```

Comment: ok ill try it. thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge : But this code is not efficient right? If new year value is getting inserted, your query also has to be changed.

Comment: @Ulias .. correct  .. ... this is just a suggestion  for the OP  ..and is only related  to sample  and the question  provided  by OP ..but as they say in my country it is better than nothing

Comment: I disagree. 'Nothing' is better in this instance.

Comment: @scaisEdge i have created a `tblyear` and put `year` as field and inserted the years. and copied your query and change the `t.myYear` to `tblyear.year` but it gives me an error.

Comment: Update your query and add  the code you are using now .. ..